# Object (KeyEvent key) to String (Java)

Tags: java, string, object, keyevent

I have something similar to the following:
An object with the value of `KeyEvent.VK_G`.
How can I get the key letter from that object (as a `String`)?

Comment: KeyEvent.VK_G is an int. How can an Object hold this value? Is it an Integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
int someKeyCode = KeyEvent.VK_G;
Object someKeyCodeObject = new Integer(someKeyCode);
String keyString = KeyEvent.getKeyText((Integer)someKeyCodeObject);
```

Which would give "G" in this case.

Comment: Its can idea, but it says that I cannot convert my Object variable into an int, help?

Comment: So what is your object? Is it an `Integer`? Is it an `Integer` cast down to an `Object`? If so, do `KeyEvent.getKeyText((Integer)yourObject)`

Comment: Thanks! LOL I was using (int) myObject instead of (Integer) myObject, heh heh ...

Answer (score 7):

By using `KeyEvent.getKeyChar()` (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar()).

Comment: Thanks, but remember, it is represented by an Object variable, not a KeyEvent variable..

Comment: So cast it? `((KeyEvent) event).getKeyChar()`

Comment: Where are you getting the integer from? Presumably a `KeyEvent` object. Use that object instead of the integer.

Comment: The integer comes from the VK_G part, i presume

Comment: What I’m saying is you probably have the event object somewhere.